# I was deleting programs I do not use and found a very generic, unidentifiable program called 'files opened'

Tags: windows-7

I was deleting programs I do not use and found a very generic, unidentifiable program called 'files opened'.

When I tried to uninstall it, a pop up box said:

"It is a small helper application that will help you open files your system does not recognize. This file does not slow your PC or interfere with your work in any way. It is here to help you open file you otherwise could not open."

Then it just says are you sure you want to uninstall?

What the heck is this?

Comment: How is this "not a real question"?  It's clear to me she's asking for someone to identify the "files opened" program and vouch for its validity as a genuine application.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like malware, spyware, or a virus.  Legitimate programs do not include the part that says 'it will not harm your computer in any way'.  That is something only malware programs think to add to their description.  You do not need a program to help you open files that your system does not recognize, you just need to install an application that will open them.  For example, if your system doesn't recognize .docx files, you install Microsoft Word.  If you're not sure what programs can open a particular type of file, you do a google search for the file extension to find the right program.

I would scan your computer with a good antivirus program.  And/or manually remove the program.  If you can remove it with the add/remove programs control panel item, that is even better.